# How to safely cancel the git checkout operation if it is taking too long

Tags: git

The git checkout operation  to my master branch is taking too long (30 min +). I cannot see any progress, what should I do so as not to cause any problem?

Comment: cancel and try it again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: That sounds a bit like "Doctor, I broke my arm and it hurts." "Well, let's cancel that broken arm and try breaking it again to see if it hurts less." Wouldn't it be better to troubleshoot it to see _why_ it's taking so long, and fix that issue instead?

Comment: Well I was working on a Unity project in a big branch, and tried to checkout to the master where my opened  (in Unity editor) current Scene file didn't exist ,as well as many files and objects in the current opened scene. So I closed Unity and tried again and the checkout did happen in a second. So I suppose that git could not access and delete the scene because of Unity.

Comment: Windows defaults to "locking" files. A program that has a file locked will block most other programs from doing anything with that file. It seems like this is what got you here. (Linux has the same ability, but it's called "advisory" locking rather than "mandatory", because both programs must *ask for locking advice* rather than just being automatically locked out.) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows for more.

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

So it was that I had a file (Scene) opened in Unity editor, while git was trying to access it and delete it. So I canceled the operation, deleted manually the .git/index.lock file, tried again and finished in 1 second.